# Getting process ram usage in megabytes

Tags: c#, memory, process, ram

I'm trying to retrieve the ram usage of my console application and for this purpose I'm using :

```
var ramUsage = Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64;
```

However the value that is returned by `WorkingSet64` is really big and I assume those are kbs tho I'm not 100% sure do I need to divide the number by 1024 to get the megabytes or I need to divide it by 1024*1024 ?

Can anyone shed some light on what exactly is the value returned by `Process.WorkingSet64`.

Comment: The "working set" *does* have a specific meaning on Windows (which you can find using Google), but that meaning is not particularly relevant for you as an application developer. In a garbage-collected environment like .NET, on a system with plenty of extra memory, the working set is likely to grow extremely large and become very unreflective of how much memory your application actually requires. What are you trying to *do* with this value? If you are trying to analyze memory usage, you need to use an actual memory profiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.workingset64(v=vs.110).aspx), the number returned by this property is in bytes.

Therefore, to convert it to kilobytes, you would divide it by 1024. To convert it to megabytes, you would divide it by 1024<sup>2</sup>. And so on.

Comment: In which case to get the ram usage in mb we need to divide by 1024*1024 right ?

Comment: @dB.Employee Technically yes, but be careful because there's controversy on whether in terms of memory usage its 1024 or 1000 :P

Comment: There is no controversy. Windows unambiguously uses the binary representation, 1 kilobyte == 1024 bytes.

Comment: I agree there is no controversy here, powers of 2 are used for digital devices such as the computer and round numbers like 1000 are only used in analog devices if i'm not wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The `Process.WorkingSet64` property is returned in bytes.
As per the MSDN article about the Property:

> Property Value
>   Type: System.Int64
>
> The amount of physical memory, in bytes, allocated for the associated process.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.workingset64%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

In Windows, in order to get the value in megabytes you are correct in that you divide by 1024 * 1024

```
var ramAllocation = Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64;
var allocationInMB = ramUsage / (1024 * 1024);
```

Side Note: Windows uses the JEDEC standard where 1 kilobyte = 1024 bytes. The IEC standard defines 1 kilobyte = 1000 bytes and 1 kibibyte = 1024 bytes. OSX after 10.6 uses ICE megabytes so 1 kilobyte = 1000 bytes. Some Linux distros, like Ubuntu after 10.10, use ICE prefixes (1 mebibyte = 1024 kibibyte and 1 megabyte = 1000 kilobytes). This is why sometimes when you purchase a HDD it seems smaller in Windows (1MB = 1024kB) than the advertised size (usually 1MB = 1000 kB).

Also, Cody Gray pointed out this is the number of **allocated** bytes, not the number of **used** bytes. OS's allocate more memory than the exact number of bytes the program uses, and generally, don't reclaim the memory immediately after it is not in use.

Comment: Windows uses the [JEDEC 100B.01](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JEDEC_memory_standards#Unit_prefixes_for_semiconductor_storage_capacity) standard, which says that a kilobyte (KB) is 1024 bytes. Why doesn't it use kibibytes? Because that unit wasn't established until 1998, and Windows had to make the decision about which prefix to use a *very* long time before 1998. Even if they were to get over the fact that a kibi- prefix sounds stupid and no one actually uses it, that would only affect the presentation in the user interface. The APIs couldn't change. HDDs do this for marketing reasons only.

Comment: @CodyGray I edited my answer so it was clearer that this is due to different standards not due to any error eg. in implementation, design. I also agree it is stupid, but it is still in use and adopted by IEEE, NIST, EU standards to use the two prefixes.